# Printing ArrayList of 2D arrays in a specific format

Tags: java

I'm trying to save an ArrayList to a text file in a particular format. It's in the correct format but it only prints out the color of one element in the ArrayList of blocks. I know the problem lies with the getBlockColor() method, what's the best way to implement this method? Here's what I've got so far.

This is the method that is in the class with the ArrayList of frames.

```
public void saveFrames(String fileName) {
    System.out.println("**method save writes data back to a file "
            + fileName);
    try {
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        outfile.println(frames.size());
        outfile.println(Frame.getCOLUMNS());
        for (Frame f : frames) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                    Color a = f.getBlockColor();
                    if (a.equals(Color.white)) {
                        outfile.print("w");
                    }
                    if (a.equals(Color.orange)) {
                        outfile.print("o");
                    }
                    if (a.equals(Color.red)) {
                        outfile.print("r");
                    }
                    if (a.equals(Color.yellow)) {
                        outfile.print("y");
                    }
                    if (a.equals(Color.green)) {
                        outfile.print("g");
                    }
                    if (a.equals(Color.blue)) {
                        outfile.print("b");
                    }

                }
                outfile.println("");
            }
        }
        outfile.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found try again");
    }
}
```

This is the code from the frame that is supposed to get the color of the blocks.

```
public Color getBlockColor() {
    for (int ROWS = 0; ROWS < 20; ROWS++) {
        for (int COLUMNS = 0; COLUMNS < 20; COLUMNS++) {
            blockColor = blocks[ROWS][COLUMNS].getBackground();
        }
    }
    return blockColor;
}
```

Comment: `getBlockColor()` always returns `blocks[19][19].getBackground()`. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a small mistake in getting the block color. 
I guess you were supposed to return the color for a specific row and column, like this:

```
public Color getBlockColor(int row, int column) {
    return blocks[row][column].getBackground();
}
```